# HTML forms without database

Tags: html

I want to build a form within html to ask for user contact info. Do I absolutely need a database to store & retrieve that data (user contact info)? How do I do that?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do.  Technically if all you need is for the information to be processed once (such as sent to you in an email) then you can just do that, no need for a database.  If you want to collect and store the data over time and use it to drive functionality in the website, then a database would be good for that.

Answer (score 3):

Check [www.enformed.io](http://www.enformed.io), you don't need a database to manage your contact forms. And also has a couple of interesting features, like setting the redirect after submiting, and email customization.  Works great to me.

Answer (score 2):

**No you don't.**

But you have to use a server side technology as php  to send you the data by email or any other way. The database is just a way to store the data.

Comment: +1 Using a database is a wise idea, but not compulsory. You can store data in flat files (text, csv, xml or json) to keep it simple.

Comment: "A database is an organized collection of data", so even a collection of emails is a database, just not in a common and convenient form.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I absolutely need a database to store & retrieve that data (user contact info)?

Yes, and no. If you want to store data on a server, and retrieve that data from the server, then yes (of course you can store it in JSON or CSV, which gives you less power but is much simpler). This option gives you much more control over the data, and you can do things like:

- have users log in
- have users share data with other users
- send emails with data

But if you simply want to store certain information for a user's session, then you can use cookies or session storage.

> How do I do that?

That part's more complicated. If you want to store data in a database, then you can use one of the dozens of DB systems out there, such as MySQL, MongoDB, PostgreSQL, etc. Another option is [Firebase](http://www.firebase.com) which allows you to store your data on secure, external servers, and access that data on the client side.

You'll also need some sort of server-side framework, such as PHP, Django, Rails, or Node.

Answer (score 0):

***A database is an organized collection of data***. 
You have few options:

1. You can send the data to your mail and store all the mails
2. You can aggregate all the data in a file on your server
3. You can use a know database like MySQL, SQLServer, Oracle etc...
4. Some more ways of collecting data...

All of the above are **databases**, some are simple and will give you a hard time retrieving your data later.

In all of the above you'll need a server side application/script that will handle the saving operation.

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions might be the use of third-party services to handle the contact data like formspree.io.

```
<form action="http://formspree.io/you@email.com" method="post">  
<input type="name" name="name">
<input type="email" name="_replyto">   
<textarea name="body"></textarea>   
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Include the above code on your contact web page. Change you@email.com with your own email address. Include a name-attribute in all form elements as required to receive the submission data.

Configuration is easy. Submit a form once from the production environment. Reply to the configuration email ASAP and you are all set.

Check out the following article:

https://medium.com/@AbhiXpert/contact-form-without-a-database-for-static-websites-in-two-minutes-5318b02a1eab

Answer (score -1):

Yes you need to have a database to store and retrieve that data, it all depends upon the number of users you have if you have many users who use that form than I guess you need to save them in a database.

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp